# How to recreate variables based on sorted order of values

Tags: variables, stata

Say that I have data like the following:

```
clear all
input age1 age2 age3 age4 
15 10 4 2
2 5 6 8
8 0 6 .
2 2 4 9
9 9 1 .
2 5 . .
end
```

There are four variables, all of which need not have values. An observation can have variables that take on the same value (ties). The problem is that I would like them sorted such that `age1` contains the highest value, `age2` contains the second highest, and so on.

How can I go about doing this? Here is what I would like the new variables to look like:

```
clear all
input age1a age2a age3a age4a
15 10 4 2
8 6 5 2
8 6 0 .
9 4 2 2
9 9 1 .
5 2 . .
end
```

This would enable me to achieve my goal of calculating the distance between the highest age and the second highest age:

```
gen space1_2 = age1a - age2a
```

Result:

```
space1_2
5
2
2
5
0
3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two methods:

1. `reshape`, `sort`, `reshape`
2. use `rowsort` from the *Stata Journal* https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0900900107

```
clear all
input age1 age2 age3 age4 
15 10 4 2
2 5 6 8
8 0 6 .
2 2 4 9
9 9 1 .
2 5 . .
end

gen id = _n 
reshape long age, i(id) j(which)
gsort id -age 
by id: replace which = _n 
reshape wide age, i(id) j(which)

list, sep(0)

     +--------------------------------+
     | id   age1   age2   age3   age4 |
     |--------------------------------|
  1. |  1     15     10      4      2 |
  2. |  2      8      6      5      2 |
  3. |  3      8      6      0      . |
  4. |  4      9      4      2      2 |
  5. |  5      9      9      1      . |
  6. |  6      5      2      .      . |
     +--------------------------------+
```

```
clear all
input age1 age2 age3 age4 
15 10 4 2
2 5 6 8
8 0 6 .
2 2 4 9
9 9 1 .
2 5 . .
end

rowsort age?, gen(sage1-sage4) descending highmissing 
list, sep(0)

     +-----------------------------------------------------------+
     | age1   age2   age3   age4   sage1   sage2   sage3   sage4 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |   15     10      4      2      15      10       4       2 |
  2. |    2      5      6      8       8       6       5       2 |
  3. |    8      0      6      .       8       6       0       . |
  4. |    2      2      4      9       9       4       2       2 |
  5. |    9      9      1      .       9       9       1       . |
  6. |    2      5      .      .       5       2       .       . |
     +-----------------------------------------------------------+
```